# Decoding a tag in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, html, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to know if there is an alternative for this in ASP.NET MVC:

```
<input type="file" name="filePath" id="file" />
```

I would like to have it with some code sample:

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.FilePath,1,32,null)%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own Html helper, that will render this html code for you. You can use [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) or [this video](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-html-helper-for-an-mvc-application) to get some knowledge about how to make it.